# Delete a last node of linked list given pointer to that node

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to delete the last node of the linkedlist, given pointer only to that node.

I wrote the below implementation, but isn't working.

I already visited majority of SO questions regarding this subject, but none of them shows how to delete last node of linked list, if there's only one pointer to that node ?

Am I missing anything here ?

```
class Node {

        Node next;
        int value;

        Node(int val) {
                this.value = val;
                this.next = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
                Node cur = this;
                String str = "";

                while(cur != null) {
                        str += cur.value+"->";
                        cur = cur.next;
                }

                return str;
        }
}

class DeleteNodeLL {

    public static void deleteNode(Node current) {
        Node temp;
        if(current.next == null) {
            current = null;
            return;
        } else {
            current.value = current.next.value;
            temp = current.next;
            temp = null;
            current.next = current.next.next;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Node n1 = new Node(25);
        Node n2 = new Node(1);
        Node n3 = new Node(36);
        Node n4 = new Node(9);
        Node n5 = new Node(14);

        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = n4;
        n4.next = n5;
        n5.next = null;

        System.out.println("Original linkedlist :");
        System.out.println(n1);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("After deleting a node :");
        deleteNode(n5);
        System.out.println(n1);
    }
}
```

Output :-

> Original linkedlist :
>   25->1->36->9->14->
>
> After deleting a node :
>   25->1->36->9->14->

Comment: you should make the previous node point to null

Comment: ^ I don't have any pointer, except for pointer to last node. So your solution won't work

Comment: There is no solution that will work for single-linked list. Please recheck your assignment...

Comment: Then I don't think it would be possible because you previous node's next still has that deleted location

Comment: Without a pointer to the previous node as well, it's not possible to delete the last node.I think your prof want's you to make this observation.If you have access to the head pointer, then the given task is possible.Do you have access to head pointer?

Comment: Your example is not a Linked-List, it's a different structure; you are using connected nodes, if you want to build a linked-list; check first how it's structured: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: removal of a connected-node is done manually; a managed removal by the node requires it to have a pointer to every connected-node that is connected to it to avoid having invalid pointers and to keep the interconnection structure

Answer (score 5):

With the singly linked list it is not possible.
This is the interview questions which is typically asked in Big Shot companies which emphasizes on Data Structures.
The question is formulated as "Delete the node in single linked list given pointer to only that node"
Expected Solution:

```
public void deleteNode(Node n)
{
    if(n==null || n.next==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Delete not possible");
        return;
    }

    n.data = n.next.data;
    Node tmp = n.next;
    n.next = n.next.next;
    tmp.next = null;

    System.out.println("Node Deleted");
}
```

The idea is to copy the data from the next node to the current node and delete the next node. The solution does not work if the node is the last node (This is what candidate has to debate and point out in interview)

Hope it helps you! (Solution to your problem is a trick question, and it does not exists)

Answer (score 3):

`current = null;` doesn't do what you expect - it only sets local variable (method argument) to `null`.

What you want is impossible *with your current implementation* of the `Node` class. 
You need either a reference to the previous node inside the `Node` class (i.e. a doubly-linked list) or you have to provide a reference to some previous node to the `deleteNode` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> You *can* delete the last node from the Linked List if *reference* of
>   it's previous node is given.

However it's based on how you implement the list.

> For your implementation, you *can't* do that

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this question is to iterate over the complete list keeping the prev node pointer everytime, compare the current node with the present node. When the comparison passes, delete the last node, and point the prev node to null. Something like the code below(note: I did not compile it)

```
deleteNode(Node *node){
if(node){
currentNode = Head, prevNode = NULL;
while(currentNode != node){
prevNode = currentNode;
currentNode = currentNode -> next;
}
delete currentNode;
prevNode -> next = NULL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@asifsid88 copied and pasted the solutions from "cracking the coding", you should refer to that book to find more interesting and challenging questions.